# JavaScript Array.sort with value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array that is something like this:

```
var array = [
    'Black',
    'Black',
    'Silver',
    'Pink',
    'Black',
    'Purple',
    'Purple',
    'Black',
];
```

I would like to sort that array by value.
For example if I choose to sort by **'Black'** it would put all the Black items at the top.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Read this and check back if you don't understand: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Use `sort` method with your own custom sort function

Comment: And how would you like to sort the rest? Or just keep them in order?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var list = [

    'silver',
    'black',

    'Black',
    'Black',
    'Silver',
    'Pink',
    'Black',
    'Purple',
    'Purple',
    'Black'
];


list.sort(function (shiftToTop) {
    return function comparator (a, b) {
        var
            compareValue;

        if (a === shiftToTop) {

            compareValue = -1;

        } else if (b === shiftToTop) {

            compareValue = 1;
        } else {
            compareValue = (

                   ((a > b) && 1)
                || ((a < b) && -1)
                || ((a === b) ? 0 : compareValue)
            );
        }
        return compareValue;
    };
}('Black'));


console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using sort a functional way of doing this job would be

```js
var array = ['Black', 'Black', 'Silver', 'Pink', 'Black', 'Purple', 'Purple', 'Black'],
   sorted = array.reduce((p,c) => c === "Black" ? [c].concat(p): p.concat(c),[]);
console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

You can pass a function to sort with as evidenced here https://jsfiddle.net/d5tkrpxo/

```
ar.sort(function(a) {
    return a=="Black" ? -1 : 1;
});
```

-1 will push the item towards the beginning and +1 will move towards the end, since you have a very simple request it's just a single comparison needed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use array `sort` method with your custom function, while the variable is `Black` give as result `1`, otherwise use string compare function to sort the rest:

```js
var array = [
    'Black',
    'Black',
    'Silver',
    'Pink',
    'Black',
    'Purple',
    'Purple',
    'Black',
];
console.info(array);

var sortBy = "Black";
array.sort(function(a, b){
  if(b == sortBy) {
    return 1;
  }
  return a.localeCompare(b);
});
console.info(array);
```

Comment: It would probably be good to explicitly return `-1` when `a` is equal to the special value and `1` when `b` is equal. Weird things can happen when the sort comparison function is not consistent.

Comment: @Pointy: What exactly do you mean? It is working properly isn't it?

Comment: Well, the problem is that your comparator function may return inconsistent results. If `b` is "Black" and "a" is "Apple", it will indicate that `b` needs to be first. However, if the `.sort()` mechanism passes the same two parameters in the opposite order, it will say that "Apple" should go first.